# MySql - Count last consecutive days

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I have a MySql table like this

| userId | dateTime | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 2022-07-10 06:54:41 | 'IN' |
| user1 | 2022-07-10 12:54:41 | 'OUT' |
| user1 | 2022-07-11 06:54:41 | 'IN' |
| user1 | 2022-07-11 12:54:41 | 'OUT' |
| user3 | 2022-07-11 06:54:41 | 'IN' |
| user3 | 2022-07-11 11:00:41 | 'OUT' |
| user2 | 2022-07-11 07:00:41 | 'IN' |
| user2 | 2022-07-11 15:00:41 | 'OUT' |
| user1 | 2022-07-13 06:54:41 | 'IN' |
| user1 | 2022-07-13 12:54:41 | 'OUT' |
| user1 | 2022-07-15 06:54:41 | 'IN' |
| user1 | 2022-07-15 06:54:41 | 'OUT' |
| user1 | 2022-07-16 06:54:41 | 'IN' |
| user1 | 2022-07-16 06:54:41 | 'OUT' |

if I filter by user1 I want to say the last count of the days consecutives that have status IN.

In this example I was the query return me 2 days because the user1 have last IN status consecutive in 15-07 and 16-07.

Can anyone help me with this query?

Comment: What _version_ of MySQL are you using (e.g. 5.7, 8.0, etc.) ?

Comment: What if the data is not consistent (there is no according OUT for some IN or backward)? What if the date in IN and according OUT differs?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 8.0.13

Comment: @Akina if at one in we don't have out we consider 2 days. Example if user1 go in on the 19-07 and go out the 22-07 we consider 3 days consecutive

Comment: *we consider 3 days consecutive* I count 4 days (19,20,21,22). And what about data consistency?

Comment: @Akina sorry, my error. For the data consistency, we can have a IN in the 15-07 for the user1 and a OUT in the 17-07, we don't have 2 IN if we don't have one OUT. Example if in the same day we have 2 IN in different time, we can have one OUT in the same date or two OUT in the same date, but we don't have 2 IN in the same date and for the same user without an OUT after the first IN